# How to connect and place a file on an azure virtal machine from azure function apps?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-virtual-machine

I need to place files as they appear in a blob into an azure virtual machine through an azure function app. I can create an azure function with a blob trigger but how can I connect to the azure VM from c# code and place the file in a folder on the virtual machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, to directly connect to the Azure VM does not have many possibilities. Azure just can manage the resources in their platform. Maybe you can execute the commands inside the VM through the Azure SDK, but I'd better use another way to place the files in a folder on the virtual machine.

Here is the way I think it's better, it has two different forms. One you can [mount the blob to the VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-how-to-mount-container-linux), then when the files change, it will also display in the VM. Another is to [mount an Azure file share to the VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/nb-no/azure///virtual-machines/linux/mount-azure-file-storage-on-linux-using-smb), and you can use Azure Function with a blob trigger to copy the file that you want to place to the file share, then it will also display in the VM.

Comment: Thank you very much! Blobs were generated into a container. Have changed it to a file share and shared it with the VM it works..Thankyou !